# How to convert a JSON file to UTF-8 format in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, json

I was able to generate a JSON file using c++ & verified with [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com/) .The file I am generating has correct format [No matters whatever is there is file]. As I am new to Encoding/Decoding so do not have much idea related to this at this instance .Is there any way I can convert this JSON file to UTF-8 format in c or c++ .

Comment: A simple ASCII text file is also a  valid UTF-8 file, so you need to describe why your file isn't UTF-8. Otherwise, there's nothing to convert.

Comment: I believe that JSON is based on UTF-8, so any valid JSON is also valid UTF-8. Check the according standard though. That said, it's unclear what your problem actually is.

Comment: @user3386109 my file is not UTF-8 because : i use cout <<"{[]}" ;
so it just prints what i need & then .json extension .

Comment: I suppose if you're on Windows, that could be a problem. If you open that file with a hex editor, what do you see?

Comment: IETF RFC 7159 title _The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format_ says `JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.`

Comment: @Marichyasana this is what i want to know . How can we do it using c++ ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can convert this JSON file to UTF-8 format in c or c++ .

you are not saying from what encoding you want to convert, if you have json text in unicode - then below example shows how to convert it to utf-8.

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
   // On input in unicode
   std::wstring uStr = L"\u0105"; // polish a with ogonek

   // Convert uStr to utf-8
   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
   std::string result = convert.to_bytes(uStr);

   // Output result,
   // U+0105 is converted to : U+00c4, U+0085,
   std::cout << "U+" << std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << uStr[0] << std::endl;
   for ( char c : result ) {
    unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
    std::cout << "U+" << std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') <<  static_cast<int>(uc) << ", ";
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to convert default text to UTF-8 . (Say any JSON data)

Comment: @BharatJain if you have default text - ie. ASCII only characters then there is nothing to convert - its already in UTF-8. You must define what default text means.

Comment: @BharatJain to learn what encoding your json is you must look either into API specs (maybe you get that json from some web service?), or into how it is generated in sources. You might for example see that there is code that puts surenames of employees into json from database, such texts surely will contain various unicode characters that are non ASCII.